# How to have a save button that opens the save as window?

Tags: html, button, save

I am working with a local html website and i want my save button to save the whole page (that will open the save as window).

I don't have an idea how to do it.

please help me with this thanks.

Comment: In addition to my question, and that will work on this browsers google chrome, Firefox, IE. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this code but insert the url of the webpage
HTML

```
<button type='button'><a href='your url here' download>Save</a></button>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried to use this code and it only work in google chrome. Is there any code that will also work on any browser?